# Add and Subtract Dates Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, timedelta

I only have datetime, timedelta and date modules in my python. Unfortunately I’ll not be able to use relativedelta to simply add months and years easily.

I would need some advice in adding months and years to a date. Have been trying but can’t think of a better way to take into account for those have >30 days, Leap year.

```
30days = Date.today() + timedelta(days=30)
Dformat = 30days.strftime(“%Y-%m-%d”)
```

Anyone has a way to add different months and years in a better way given I only have these limited modules?

Comment: So are you trying to add `30 days` to lets say, jan, to get output as feb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know no builtin way. But it can easily done *by hand*:

```
def add_year(dt, years):
    """
    Add years years to dt and return the new value.

    dt can be a date or datetime, years must be an integer value (may be negative)
    """
    try:
        return dt.replace(year=dt.year + years)
    except ValueError:
        # the day that does not exist in new month: return last day of month
        return dt.replace(year=dt.year + years, month=dt.month + 1, day=1
              ) - timedelta(days=1)

def add_month(dt, months):
    """
    Add months months to dt and return the new value.

    dt can be a date or datetime, months must be an integer value (may be negative)
    """
    y, m = divmod(months + dt.month, 12)
    try:
        return dt.replace(year=dt.year + y, month=m)
    except ValueError:
        # the day that does not exist in new month: return last day of month
        return dt.replace(year=dt.year + y, month=m + 1, day=1
                          ) - timedelta(days=1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = date(2020, 12, 10)
>>> add_month(d, 3)
datetime.date(2021, 3, 10)
>>> add_month(d, -13)
datetime.date(2019, 11, 10)
```

It even handles shorter months:

```
>>> d =date(2017,1,30)
>>> add_month(d, 1)
datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)
```

Comment: note that this will fail if the initial date is Feb 29th in a leap year and you try to add a number of years that is not a multiple of 4 etc. - [dateutil.relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) might offer a safer way to go.

Comment: @MrFuppes: You are right, I was not cautious enough on my first code. Should be better now. BTW OP explicitely declared *I’ll not be able to use relativedelta*.

Comment: Ok seems like I should be more cautious reading the question ^^ Actually reads like a homework assignment; "not able to use package x" sounds like "use the hard way and learn something"

Comment: Managed to figure out with relativddelta installation. But the solution works too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different possibilities. I give you an example which take a date and return the last day of quarter but you can, obviously, apply this methodology to any frequency, So:

If you have datetime, you can have a object dt defines as a datetime.date

You can build a function get_quarter_end which take as input a datetime.date object and return the last day of quarter.

```
def get_quarter_end(dt):
    # dt: datetime.date
    # firts we get the year of the next quarter
    nextQtYr = dt.year + (1 if dt.month > 9 else 0)
    # then the month
    nextQtFirstMo = (dt.month - 1) // 3 * 3 + 4
    nextQtFirstMo = 1 if nextQtFirstMo == 13 else nextQtFirstMo
    # finally the day (first day of the next quarter)
    nextQtFirstDy = date(nextQtYr, nextQtFirstMo, 1)
    # so we have all information about the next quarter, because we are  
    # interested by the date at the end of the quarter, we just need to 
    # substract 1 day: 
    return nextQtFirstDy - timedelta(days=1)
```